# Random image loader

Tags: images, shortcode

I'm trying to load a random image from my child them images directory each time the page loads.

I'm loading it as a shortcode right now.  This is the code i'm using:

```
function footer_image () {
   $imagesDir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/footer/';
   $imagespec =  get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/footer/footer-fishing.png'; //for testing

   $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

   $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)].'there';

   return $randomImage;//this returns nothing.
   return $imagespec; //this returns the correct url for the image
   return $imagesDir; //this returns the correct url for the images directory
}
add_shortcode ('footer-image', 'footer_image');
```

in the end I want to use return `$randomImage`, but in my testing i've commented out that line and individually added each of the other returns to see if they are working.  They both do.

So it would appear I have something wrong with the `$images` or `$randomImage` variable.

Comment: If you’re not sure about `$images’ then pump it into your display with `print_r()` or something like that so you can see what it has stored. In the `$randomImage` declaration `array_rand()` can return more than one value unless you set the second parameter to 1. Also adding the string ‘there’ onto the end of `$randomImage` looks like it might be a mistake.

Comment: i'll try print_r(), the "there" was just to see if anything was coming out at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try to see if this works, I used `scandir` because I prefer it. The problem was that `glob`, like `scandir`, only works with paths on the server's file system, not URLs:

```
function footer_image(){

    $imagesDir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/images/footer';

    $imagesUri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/footer/';

    $images = array_diff( scandir( $imagesDir, 1 ), array( '.', '..' ) );

    $randomImage = $images[ array_rand( $images ) ];

    $footerImage = '<img src="' . $imagesUri . $randomImage . '" alt="Footer image">';

    return $footerImage;
}
add_shortcode ( 'footer-image', 'footer_image' );
```

To use a shortcode in a page/theme template:

```
echo do_shortcode("[footer-image]");
```

P.S. Instead, if you created a taxonomy in the media library for example `footer` and took those images, you could use more attributes (`alt`, `description`, `size`, etc.), improve SEO and make the website more responsive. What do you think about it?